# Use of Jakarta Validation annotation

Tags: java, validation

If I want to publish a simple utils API. Is it recommended to use the Jakarta Validation annotations, basically on every input parameter of every public method, to signify which needs to be @NonNull or @Positive for instance ?

It seems like a good way to signal these restrictions to users, but maybe it is too much to use it everywhere ? When is it necessary, and when is it not recommended ?

Talking about regular SE Java here, no app, no rest API, no Spring or whatever.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: @dan1stiscrying thanks, I split it then, hoping all of them still make sense separately

Comment: By the way, “Bean” is being dropped from the name of that technology. The new name is simply [*Jakarta Validation*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/).

Answer (score 0):

With no real answer to my several questions on the subject but a few comments I'll summarize my current understanding. Please feel free to have a more complete answer if you have more direct knowledge.

1. The API is mainly meant for validation of beans, coming from users, through web API (and so deserialization).
2. It's possible to use the implementation (hibernate-validator) to validate explicitly, but it is more meant to be used within a framework that handles it automatically.
3. It still seems to me that in a regular API (no web, no framework) they would have an interest as a simple declarative documenting effect, but could not find information on this use. If used only declaratively I assume the validator implementation is not needed.
4. Although, since there is no automatic handling, nor IDE simple validation on the annotation itself, you still need to implement it yourself. And once your method handles, let's say a null parameter, by doing something specific (default return value or throw exception), you can then document this behaviour and the @NotNull becomes more of a suggestion than a constraint.